# Is there any advantage in using Google's IAM on Android?

Tags: authentication, android, architecture, identity-management, single-sign-on

We are building a few corporate apps for field workers / front office. In most cases each user will have their own device, but there are some shared devices (for example reception). The devices are going to be Android and we are planning to develop native apps.

Giving that these are Android devices / apps, is there any advantage in using Google's IAM (Cloud IAM) over other solutions (Azure AD, Okta, AWS IAM etc.)?
For example, would it be possible to unlock the device using the account's login and automatically be logged to all other apps?